# VS Code Key Binding for python file execution in IPython

Tags: python, ipython, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code with Python extension by Don Jayamanne, and iPython running in the shell.

I would like to configure a hot key that will run the current file in editor within iPython. Something like: **In [#]: run *current-file-in-editor***

I didn't see anything like that in the hot key list.
I did manage to configure a hot key that executes **"& python *current-file-in-editor*"**, which is a bit annoying since i have to maintain 2 shells: one for iPython and one for the OS.

Thanks,
Yanir